# filter out Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException from the Visual Studio diagnostic tools window

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dynamic, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 it comes with a Diagnostic tools window that comes up when you are debugging.  This is a great tool because it lists all kinds of good real-time data.  The problem that I am having is that I use the Viewbag pretty extensively and it the implementation of dynamics throws and catches Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException exceptions as part of their implementation.  You can see an example in the screenshot below:

[image]

This wouldn't be a problem except that each time my page loads it shows multiple exceptions on my timeline.  These false positive exceptions make real exceptions less obvious on top of making my OCD side scream.

What I would really like to do is filter out specific exceptions from the events graph/list.

**tl;dr:**  How do I remove specific exception types from the VS 2015 diagnostics event list?a

Comment: This still isn't fixed, but now use ViewData["PageTitle"], which does prevent the error from coming up on the diagnostics screen.